# What am I supposed to do with this output from brew doctor?

Tags: homebrew

I just installed homebrew and ran brewdoctor. It is giving me this error:

```
Warning: Your XQuartz (2.7.4) is outdated
Please install XQuartz 2.7.5:
  https://xquartz.macosforge.org
```

What am I supposed to do in response? `Brew install https://xquartz.macosforge.org` Or do I need to translate that URL into the name of a brew package?

Answer (score 4):

See [this issue](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/24094) on homebrew's github...

You'd just go to https://xquartz.macosforge.org and download XQuartz 2.7.5 and install it.

Comment: That xquartz download link doesn't work for me. I get a page that says "Forbidden!" and is otherwise blank. Same with the link by @sufinawaz.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because one or more of your installed brew apps depend on XQuartz to work.

You can't install XQuartz via brew, so you need to go to that website to install it.

Answer (score 0):

You can download XQuartz 2.7.7 from http://xquartz.macosforge.org/downloads/SL/XQuartz-2.7.7.dmg (replace 2.7.7 with the latest number) and open it with OS X's installer to install it. After you install it, run `brew doctor` to see if your system is ready to brew ;)